# Как работать с куками через CookieJar в приложении?

Tags: java, android, мобильная-разработка, мобильные-приложения

Как работать с куками используя [PersistentCookieJar for OkHttp 3](https://github.com/franmontiel/PersistentCookieJar) ?

Вот пример:

```
ClearableCookieJar cookieJar =
            new PersistentCookieJar(new SetCookieCache(), new SharedPrefsCookiePersistor(context));


OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
            .cookieJar(cookieJar)
            .build();
```

А как это работает, не очень понятно.
Например, как отправить куку с запросом, или как ее получить из запроса?